# Calling Javascript function from a href

Tags: javascript, html, href

Background information:
When I press the Flag Property button, a module should pop up allowing me to send an email to a particular account alerting systems that this particular property should be flaged. There is another button, Email Property, that allows you to email the information regarding the property to anyone you want.

This is the code that I have associated with the buttons. As you can see both buttons will lead to the same javascript function. But I need them to point to two different functions. How do I do that?

```
<li><a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs purple fire_the_modal" data-propid="'.$row_mem['propertyid'].'"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Flag Property </a></li>

<li><a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs purple fire_the_modal" data-propid="'.$row_mem['propertyid'].'"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Email Property </a></li>
```

I wrote the script that actually executes in another file. 
This is the header I wrote for that

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Could I just associate let us the flag property with

```
<a href="javascript1:; and correspondingly   <script type="text/javascript1">
```

I am pretty new to javascript, so I am not sure if this is even right thing to do.

Comment: `href="javascript:;"` means "Run this JavaScript and use the result as a new document, or stay on the same page if there is no document". It is horrible, you should never use it (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript ) and it isn't what is triggering your JS. There is nothing in the code you've shared with us what will cause JS to run when the link (to nowhere) is clicked. It must be somewhere else.

Comment: seeing that you are using some data attributes, wouldn't it be slightly easier to reference the function name to such attributes instead of using the href? you already have the job almost done, the fastest (and cleanest) solution is implementing a .click listener on fire_the_modal and add a data attribute to each <a> referencing the function it needs to call. (also, preventing the default <a> click behavior)

Comment: @briosheje could you please show me an example? could i just have two different .click listeners? meaning have the flag property respond to fire_the modal and email property respond to fire_the_modal1

Comment: @Ria: something like that http://jsfiddle.net/fybfreu8/ Or just use different click listeners, your choice ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You define a function in your other script and then you call that function when your link is clicked.  So you would put all the code you want to execute from that other script into a function.  Then, include that script into your page with `<script src="xxx.js"></script>`.  That will make the function be defined in the web page so it can be called.

There are several different ways to call that function from the link.  You can either put `javascript:myFunc()` as the href or you can register a click handler for the link.  Registering an event handler is the generally recommended way to handle a click on a link.

If you don't know how to set up a click handler for a link, here's an article about the basics: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers

So, your external script in xxx.js would look like this:

```
function myFunc() {
   // put your code here
}
```

Here's an example of a simple event handler:

```js
function log(msg) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.textContent = msg;
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}


document.getElementById("myLink").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  log("clicked");
});
```

```html
<a href="#" id="myLink">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: <script src="xxx.js"></script> Do you mean to add that with the href?

Comment: @Ria - no, the script tag would go either in the `<head>` section of your document or in the `<body>` section.  The idea is that the script is loaded in advance and that defines your function.  The function can then be called when the click happens.  This is pretty fundamental stuff that is required so I'm thinking that you may benefit from some online tutorials about how web pages and Javascript work in general.

Comment: Why the downvote to this answer?  I'm attempting to explain the basics of how an external script works to the OP.  If you think my answer needs improving, then please explain why so I can improve it.

Comment: @Ria - I added an example of setting up an event handler to my answer.